# PHP How do I call into class namespace from command line

Tags: php, namespaces

This works in the context of a web application but does not work when I use the same syntax as part of a nightly batch script invoked with "php -f"

```
$db = Lifestyle\Application::getDependency('db');
```

I'm getting:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in <b>/home1/lowens/public_html/dev/batch/nightly.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />

<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>/home1/lowens/public_html/dev/batch/nightly.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
```

Why?

Comment: version 5.3.27 according to phpinfo called thru the web site, I'll check via the command line......

Comment: Try changing that forward slash to a backslash in your namespace...

Comment: 5.2 aha I'll have to find the 5.3 executable.  Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's supposed to be a backslash: `$db = Lifestyle\Application::getDependency('db');`